# Make floated elements maintain their position

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ueaa9/). The problem I am facing is next:
When the x axis of the screen is smaller than the y axis the button toolbar(black) jumps to the top of the screen. And if the x axis is even smaller my fieldsets expand vertically jumping out of the botton toolbar. How to fix this and make fieldsets maintain their position?
I tried using `overflow` but didn't make it work.

Comment: i didn't understand what you are trying to understand? you wanna black and red screen as it always when screen go larger or smaller? Let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `float:left`

Set the `.dhFieldset` elements to be `display:inline-block;` and then set their container `.dhButtonToolbar` to be `white-space:nowrap;`

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
    .dhFieldset{
        display:inline-block; /*Added this line and remove the float:left*/
        height:37px;
        width:auto;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
    .dhButtonToolbar {
        height: 60px;
        left:5px;
        width:100%;
        right: 5px; 
        white-space:nowrap; /*added this line*/
    }
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Ueaa9/4/